# c# winform how to start a process on top of main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried `process.start("cmd.exe","/c"+filename)`, but the command line window didn't terminate itself.

Is there anyone know how to start a new process on top of main form?

Thanks

Comment: Why you didn't call process.start(filename)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "on top of main form" ?

Comment: I think he means that when his form closes, so does the spawned process

Answer (score 2):

Using `Process.Start` is the correct solution to call an external application. The new process should even gain the input focus.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
```